# What was the joke behind the headless clone of Spiro Agnew in Futurama?

Tags: futurama

In Futurama, [President Nixon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Nixon)'s head gets to be president again, this time of all of Earth, and is later often seen with the headless clone of Spiro Agnew. [Spiro Agnew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiro_Agnew) was Nixon's vice president from 1969 to 1973. Nixon's presidency was both before my time, and in a different country. As such, I don't get why Futurama brought him back as a headless clone.

What was the joke behind the headless clone of Spiro Agnew?

Comment: Agnew's intelligence was not widely respected is what I recollect from those days.

Answer (score 6):

I’ve always understood the joke being, Agnew was Nixons lacky in reality, and is his lacky in the show, but in a classic evil villain style.

Since Nixon doesn’t have a body, his new Agnew clone lacky won’t have a head.

It’s a common bad guy trope of henchmen being big but [Dumb Muscle](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DumbMuscle), to a bad guy being small but ‘smart’.

**Dumb Muscle:**

> The tendency for strength and intellect to be inversely proportional. The Big Guy and The Brute are usually slightly dim at the very least (with The Smart Guy and [The Evil Genius](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheEvilGenius) at the opposite end of the scale; incredibly intelligent, but knocked over by a stiff breeze).

Agnew literally doesn’t have a head and is just a body, and Nixon who is portrayed as a villain in the show’s canon, is only a head.